# PUPPET ERROR expected chomping or indentation indicators

Tags: ruby, linux, puppet, rhel, rhel7

```
2024-02-06T12:50:38.562+01:00 ERROR [qtp488725606-52] [puppetserver] Puppet Server Error: Could not load external node results for "mynode": (<unknown>): expected chomping or indentation indicators, but found h(104) while scanning a block scalar at line 138 column 39
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/network/http/handler.rb:92:in `respond_to_errors'
2024-02-06T12:50:58.151+01:00 ERROR [qtp488725606-54] [puppetserver] Puppet Failed when searching for node "my node": Could not load external node results for "my node": (<unknown>): expected chomping or indentation indicators, but found h(104) while scanning a block scalar at line 138 column 39
```

Content of `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/network/http/handler.rb`

```rb
  def respond_to_errors(response)
    yield
  rescue Puppet::Network::HTTP::Error::HTTPError => e
    Puppet.info(e.message)
    respond_with_http_error(response, e)
  rescue StandardError => e
    http_e = Puppet::Network::HTTP::Error::HTTPServerError.new(e)
    Puppet.err([http_e.message, *e.backtrace].join("\n"))
    respond_with_http_error(response, http_e)
  end
```

```bash
postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.13

puppetdb --version
puppetdb version: 7.13.0

puppetserver --version
puppetserver version: 7.11.0

puppet --version
7.27.0
```

upgrade puppet, from 7.4  to 7.11 and puppetdb

Comment: The diagnostic says that the issue is with the output of your external node classifier.  *You* provide that, not Puppet, and we have no way to guess what yours is doing.